# Who coined the phrase "City of the World's Desire"?

Tags: byzantine-empire, ottoman-empire

In 1995, the British author Philip Mansel published a book titled ***Constantinople: City of the World's Desire***. The same phrase also appears in the game *Europa Universalis IV*: one of the Ottomans' missions is called "City of the World's Desire". The phrase seems to predate Mansel, but who coined it, and when?

According to [an article in the *Washington Post*](https://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-srv/style/longterm/books/chap1/constantinople.htm#:%7E:text=the%20Golden%20Horn.-,%27,city%20of%20the%20world%27s%20desire%27.) (which is actually an excerpt from Mansel's book), the phrase was coined by a Greek speaker:

> The walls had been built because Constantinople was, as one Byzantine had written, 'the city of the world's desire'.

But I'm struggling to find out *which* 'Byzantine' wrote those words. Can anyone else do any better?

Comment: @justCal Thank you! You obviously read it more carefully than I did!

Comment: If I remember correctly, Ionce read that a medieval writer mentioned Constantinople as "this city of the world's desire".